# Moving from screen to tmux but having trouble in copying (double click doesnt work in tmux)

Tags: putty, tmux, gnu-screen, xterm, mobaxterm

While in putty double clicking a word copies it to clipboard, I am unable to copy by doubling clicking when I am using tmux in putty. I am able to do it using SHIFT key, but I want to do it without using SHIFT

Answer (score 0):

To get PuTTY's original behavior in `tmux`, you would have to turn the mouse feature in `tmux` off.  This is a window option (see [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html)):

```
         mode-mouse [on | off | copy-mode]
                 Mouse state in modes.  If on, the mouse may be used to
                 enter copy mode and copy a selection by dragging, to
                 enter copy mode and scroll with the mouse wheel, or to
                 select an option in choice mode.  If set to copy-mode,
                 the mouse behaves as set to on, but cannot be used to
                 enter copy mode.
```

PuTTY is acting like `xterm` in this regard: xterm's [default translations](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Default-Key-Bindings) resource defines the mouse-button action when the mouse-mode is inactive, but redefines the *unshifted* mouse-clicks when mouse-mode is active.

Further reading:

- [tmux and text selection with mouse through putty](https://superuser.com/questions/300060/tmux-and-text-selection-with-mouse-through-putty)
- [4.11.3 ‘Shift overrides application's use of mouse’](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-mouseshift) (PuTTY documentation)